# Manutenção planejada: quarta-feira 03/05/2017 00:00 UTC | 21:00 BR | 00:00 PT

Tags: debate

## Versão Micro

Degradação planejada no serviço: Todos os sites do Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange em modo somente-leitura por 20 minutos na quarta-feira, 03/maio, 2017 logo após a meia-noite UTC (21h Brasília; 00h Lisboa). Vai ser vapt-vupt.

## Versão Curta

Vai haver uma degradação no serviço de até 20 minutos logo após a meia noite UTC (21h Brasília; 00h Lisboa) na quarta-feira, 03/maio, 2017. As perguntas, respostas e comentários continuarão sendo exibidas nesse esse período. **Mas os sites estarão em modo somente-leitura e não será possível perguntar, responder, comentar, editar, etc**. Não gostamos de fazer isso, mas é inevitável e vai prevenir problemas maiores no futuro. O teste não deve causar muito transtorno, já que o site continuará funcional para a maioria dos usuários. As pessoas afetadas pela paralisação vão ver um aviso.

Perguntas? Deixe um comentário ou resposta abaixo.

## Versão Longa

### Em termos leigos

**Situação**:

- Nossos sites estão localizados num datacenter chamado NY (em Jersey City, NJ, EUA).
- Temos um datacenter espelhado chamado CO (em Denver, CO, EUA).
- CO é nosso datacenter para casos de falha, quando NY estiver tendo problemas (e para testes como o de agora).

**E o que vai acontecer?**

Durante a degradação do serviço, a execução vai ser passada para o CO, depois de volta para NY. Isso na tentativa de identificar quaisquer inconsistências entre os dois. É melhor descobrir esses problemas num ambiente seguro e controlado do que em uma emergência. Ao impedir a criação de conteúdo novo (ou edição do antigo) o processo se torna muito mais rápido e seguro.

**Por que?**

Fazemos testes assim para ter certeza de que estamos preparados para emergências maiores.

Melhor encontrar problemas agora, quando é fácil corrigi-los, que no meio de uma emergência (como quando o furacão Sandy tirou NY do ar). Então, como naqueles testes de incêndio, fazemos isso para ter certeza de que estamos preparados para a hora da verdade. E, infelizmente, não realizamos esse teste há um ano.

Então faremos um teste menor dia 03/maio, como preparação para um teste maior no terceiro trimestre. Ironicamente, o teste maior vai ser quase invisível aos nossos usuários, por conta do que vamos aprender com o primeiro teste.

Perguntas? Deixe um comentário ou resposta abaixo.

### Em termos técnicos

Vamos fazer um teste de falha em modo leitura para o CO, revertendo logo em seguida. No momento, CO está rodando em modo *stand by* então vamos ativá-lo para ter certeza de que tudo está bem configurado e funcionando.

Os detalhes:

- Início: Quarta, 03/Maio logo após as 21h BRT/00h WEST
- Fim: 20 minutos de modo somente-leitura
- Usuários afetados: Todos os serviços (site e chat) em modo somente-leitura por 20 minutos

O que vamos fazer:

- Ativar o datacenter CO como local primário (em modo leitura)
- Testar os serviços
- Voltar o controle para NY

O que não vamos fazer:

Nada será desligado em NY. Ele continuará rodando normalmente, para facilitar a reversão.

O que vai acontecer próximo trimestre?

Em Junho ou Julho próximos nós vamos operar do CO por uma semana (talvez 2). Há manutenção a ser feita em NY que necessita do datacenter desligado. Quando ela for terminada, vamos voltar o controle para NY. Mudanças que afetem os usuários serão muito curtas, e acontecerão nos fins de semana, para minimizar o impacto.  Vamos fazer outro post quando chegar a hora.

Perguntas? Deixe um comentário ou resposta abaixo.

Comment: Esses servidores estão mal informados, dia de greve é amanhã.

Comment: Não é anti-segurança dizer onde estão os data center? Ando a ver muito Mr. Robot ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Ou será que é *proposital* para instigar algumas mentes a testar a segurança?

Comment: @JorgeB. Não faz diferença, porque o verdadeiro datacenter são os amigos que fizemos pelo caminho

Comment: Se a manutenção é planejada, eu acho que isso não deveria ser chamado de falha, mas talvez de "redução de serviço".

Comment: @Renan faz sentido. Eram 11 da noite e eu acabei sendo literal demais na tradução de "planned failover"

Comment: @Gabe As dúvidas pertinentes postadas no [post em inglês](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295285/317427) você irá traduzir aqui ou acha que é melhor esperar para ver se teremos as mesmas curiosidades (eu particularmente tive somente após ler lá, kkk)

Comment: @Randrade Quer que eu traga um refresco e uma batata frita também? Eu to aqui pra responder as dúvidas que vocês tiverem, ué. 

Comment: @Gabe Prefiro cerveja é petiscos :p. Eu tive essas dúvidas sanadas ao ler lá, mas não sei se os outros irão ter ou nem pensariam em ter, por isso a minha dúvida

Comment: @Randrade Então pergunte aqui, ué

Comment: O que, qual cerveja eu prefiro? rsrs
Como eu disse, minhas dúvidas foram sanadas e eu só as tive após ler o post em inglês. Com isso, para mim, eu não vejo a necessidade. Porém, algu´me pode ter essas mesmas dúvidas, e isso eu não sei *prever*

Comment: @Randrade Se foram úteis pra você, o mais provável é que sejam úteis para mais alguém. E não há absolutamente nenhum efeito colateral indesejável em refazer as perguntas aqui, mesmo que você já saiba a resposta. Ou até mesmo adicionar uma resposta com o que você teve solucionado lá.

Comment: @Renan a mim mete-me mais impressão o «planejada» ;)

Comment: Deu tudo certo?

Answer (score 5):

Traduzindo, mais ou menos certo, [esta pergunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295290/317427):

Votos para **fechar ou excluir**, e o mais importante, as **flags** ainda funcionarão? Pergunto isso pois podem ter perguntas feitas com conteúdo impróprio antes das 21:00 que ficarão abertas durante estes 20 minutos.

Comment: Sim. Não será possível fazer nenhuma atividade no site durante o periodo de manutenção. Se algum caso grave realmente acontecer, nós podemos tomar as medidas necessárias direto no banco de dados.

Answer (score 5):

O Chat também ficará indisponível durante este período?

Comment: Ainda não está decidido.